# HTML/CSS navbar not working when changing from pc layout to mobile

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a nav bar that works on both pc and mobile devices but when the nav bar is in mobile mode things don't look quite right. I think its my css that's the issue I just don't know where or what is causing it.

I've had to make it on repl because its for school so not sure if that's effecting it but I've posted an invite link to the website.

This is where the website is

`https://replit.com/join/pzgmiypjtm-aidenmcginty`

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `margin-left: 20px;` when you click on the burger.
You can also change the `top: 60px;` to `top: 76px;`

[image: It looks like this]